# Multiple inputs in one command

Tags: unix, printing, grep, multiple-value

I've got something like this:

> Error_code=1; num=5;
>
> Error_code=2; num=7;
>
> Error_code=3; num=9;
>
> Error_code=1; num=2;
>
> Error_code=2; num=5;

.
.
.

And alot of error codes (about 100)
Pretend the file called performance.log

How can i use one command but each time the error code is different
Like:

```
grep -i "error_code=$x;" performance.log | awk -F";" '{print $2}' > $x_error_code.txt
```

So each time the variable x is a new value defined from error code
And when the error codes finish the script will finish

Comment: What have you already tried?  It is better if you ask a specific question rather than general advice.

Comment: what result are you expecting?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest each error code in a file

Answer (score 0):

To split the input file into individual files for each *error code*:

```
awk -F";" '{fn=substr($1, index($1,"=")+1); print $2 > fn"_error_code.txt";}' performance.log
```